# Label won't update text = " "

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Before i begin I know its messy, I'm getting it working before I clean it up. This is also just for my own knowledge growth I do not intend on rolling this out throughout the company. I have made a monitoring program to check the status of a couple of servers for one of my clients. I have managed to get all the relevant data I need from the ping to the servers, I take the data and send it to the "sort" method where it sends that to the next method which figures out which label I should change the text of, it makes it into these if statements however it just doesn't update the text.

I have already tried:

```
Application.doEvents();

Label.Refresh();

Label.Update();
```

I've tried using multithreading too see if that would perhaps force it through.

I have even tried using a button to manually update and that didn't work either.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Synergy s = new Synergy();
        s.Start();
    }

    private void Label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Sort(String Name, double P, long RTT, String Response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Inside Sort");
        if (Name.Contains("SYN-"))
        {
            SynergySort(Name, P, RTT, Response);
        }
    }

    public void SynergySort(String Name, double P, long RTT, String Response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Inside Synergy Sort");
        if (Name.Equals("SYN-DC01"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Inside DC01 SORT");
            this.SD1R.Text = RTT.ToString();
            this.SD1P.Text = P.ToString();
        }
        else if (Name.Equals("SYN-DC03"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Inside DC03 SORT");
            this.SD3R.Text = RTT.ToString();
            this.SD3P.Text = P.ToString();
        }
    }

}

public class Synergy
{

    private Form1 f = new Form1();
    private Pinger ping = new Pinger();

    public void Start()
    {
        NAS01Scan();
        DC03Scan();
        TRACKERScan();
        DC01Scan();
        VoiceScan();
        NETAPPScan();
    }

    public void NAS01Scan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pinging NAS01");
        ping.IP("172.16.xx.xxx", 5, "SYN-NAS01");
    }

    public void DC03Scan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pinging DC03");
        ping.IP("172.16.xx.xxx", 5, "SYN-DC03");
    }

    public void TRACKERScan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pinging TRACKER");
        ping.IP("172.16.xx.xxx", 5, "SYN-TRACKER");
    }

    public void DC01Scan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pinging DC01");
        ping.IP("172.16.xx.xxx", 5, "SYN-DC01");
    }

    public void NETAPPScan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pinging NETAPP");
        ping.IP("172.16.xx.xxx", 5, "SYN-NETAPP");
    }

    public void VoiceScan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pinging AVAYA_Voice");
        ping.IP("172.16.xx.xxx", 5, "SYN-AVAYA_Voice");
    }

}

public class Pinger
{

    private Form1 f = new Form1();

    public void IP(String host, int echoNum, String Name)
    {
        long totalTime = 0;
        PingReply reply = null;
        int timeout = 120;
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
        options.DontFragment = true;
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        int failed = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < echoNum; i++)
        {

            reply = pingSender.Send(host, timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                failed += 1;
                Console.WriteLine(Name + ": " + reply.Status);
            }
        }

        totalTime += reply.RoundtripTime;

        Console.WriteLine(Name + ": RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);

        Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Time in MS = " + totalTime / echoNum);

        double percent = (failed / echoNum) * 100;

        Console.WriteLine(Name + ": Percent Loss is " + percent);

        f.Sort(Name, percent, reply.RoundtripTime, reply.Status.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very common error. You create new instances of the class Form1. These instance have their own labels and you are updating these labels. However these Form1 instances are never shown so you can't see anything. The labels in the Form1 instance that you look at are never touched by your code. You need to pass the current instance of form1 through the class Synergy and down to the class Pinger.

Comment: `public class Synergy
{
    private readonly Pinger ping = new Pinger();

    public void Start(Form1 f)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}` then in the button click: `s.Start(this);`. Or pass the form to `Synergy` through its constructor.